# How to drive 5V display with ESP32-C on 3.7V LiPo battery?

Tags: power, esp32, step-up

I'm using a ESP32C3 board (with integrated battery circuit, the [Seeed Studio XIAO ESP32C3](https://www.seeedstudio.com/Seeed-XIAO-ESP32C3-p-5431.html)), running on a 3.7V LiPo battery. The board is mostly in deep sleep, so it can be battery powered for quite some time. (power consumption in deep sleep >44 μA according to the specs).

When the board wakes up from deep sleep, I'd like to power up a 5V display driver, connected via SPI to the ESP32. The display driver is an [IT8951 based board, driving a 7.8" e-paper display by Waveshare](https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/7.8inch_e-Paper_HAT)). This driver board can go to deep sleep too, but it still consumes  0.1W, so I'd like to complete disconnect it from the power when it's not updating.

Since the display + driver is running on 5V, I already figured out I need a Step-Up voltage regulator (going from 3.7V from the battery to 5V). Also, while updating the e-paper display, it draws 1.2W. So it's probably too much to hook up the Step-Up regulator to a GPIO pin of the ESP32C. **Therefore my question is: how do I connect the ESP32C, Step-Up voltage regulator, the IT8951 driven display and the 3.7V battery?**

My educated guess would be with the help of a transistor. It would be great if somebody can confirm and recommend a transistor to use (and how to connect it).

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome! Please draw a schematic and/or block diagram. Unless you need to completely disconnect your boost converter, you shouldn’t need a transistor.

Comment: I would also add that it might make more sense to use a 5V power supply and step down instead. Plus, either the USB or the BAT pin of most ESP32 dev boards can actually take in 5V and power the board - you may want to look into that.